# Chromium Sign-in issues Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: chromium

Whenever I try to sign into my chrome account via chromium on my Rpi 3, I get a "service unavailable" error message. What can I do?

Comment: You could start by making sure you have the latest Chrome, a working network and a new user profile without any changed settings or addons. If all that checks out the issue is most probably on Google side, so you're unlikely to get help here. Check out [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=405045) on their tracker.

Comment: OK, I checked it out, and its mostly about chrome impersonation viruses, which I'm sure is not my problem.

Comment: It's amazing how you managed to read only two comments mentioning the virus, while completely ignoring the rest. There seems to be relevant stuff, like running `LC_ALL=C chromium` or putting your API key in `/etc/chromium.d`.

Comment: That didn't actually work. Just FYI.